# How to add/access JSP files when using ant-jnlp-war builder?

Tags: java, jsp, ant, war, jnlp

I'm currently using the [Ant Web Start Task](http://ant-jnlp-war.sourceforge.net/) to build a fairly large JNLP project.

I've recently added some JSP files to my project.  I am having two problems however.

### Problem 1:

I can't access these files when I deploy my application.  I currently have them in a `src/jsp directory.`  I've added this directory into a jar that is being built via `<fileset dir="${jsp.dir}" includes="**/*.jsp"/>`  I can see these files in the jar, if I unzip it and explore said jar.

### Problem 2:

The ant jnlp war builder seems to be automatically generating both a web.xml and a index.html.  How do I incorporate the current web.xml (and a new index.html) page into my war file automatically, without it being rebuilt/overwritten every time?

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to a lot of this if you couldn't tell.